# Таблица справочник

Tags: sql

Имеется веб-приложение которое работает с БД. В базе есть несколько "константных" таблиц, содержимое которых остается относительно постоянным - то есть в них довольно редко меняются какие-либо данные.  Иначе говоря, это некие таблицы-справочники содержащие набор ключей и значений. Примером может быть таблица содержащая список стран. В коде приложения часто происходит обращение к этим таблицам. Например содержимое такой таблицы часто является содержимым какого-нибудь выпадающего списка. Однако обращаться строкам в этой таблице из веб-приложения по первичному ключу - не очень удачная затея на мой взгляд, так как это во первых не наглядно (совершенно непонятно, что Id равный 1 соответствует, скажем России если речь идет о таблице стран) Во вторых пусть и редко но теоретически идентификаторы могут меняться в таблице а это уже ведет к проблемам.

Был предложен вариант помимо полей Id и Name хранить в таблице поле KeyCharName и сопоставлять его в коде приложения со значениями некоего enum написав для этого соответствующие методы конвертирования. С одной стороны уже лучше и решает первые две проблемы. Но с другой появляется необходимость постоянно следить при изменениях таблицы  что значения enum в коде соответствуют значениям в таблице и к тому же это куда медленнее чем вариант работы с полем Id. 
Может кто-то знает более хорошие способы решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Я для такого же случая (список стран) делал таблицу, первичным ключом которой был `CHAR(2)`, где хранился [Alpha-2 код страны](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). Получалось, что таблица выглядит так:

```
AD | Андорра
AE | ОАЭ
AF | Афганистан
AG | Антигуа и Барбуда
...
```

Для случая настроек, я думаю, тоже можно использовать такой же вариант.

Это удобно, но не знаю, насколько это плохо в плане производительности и философии, может количество минусующих мне скажет об этом :)

Comment: не очень удобно так как во-первых хотелось бы распространять этот подход на все подобные таблицы (таблица со странами лишь для примера) а во вторых вы сами упомянули про производительность

Comment: @Andy_Reed так если вы хотите удобства, то ключ должен быть текстовые, как в примере `VARCHAR(2)`. Если же Вы введете доп. поле, то опять же суть та же и останется. Если Вы хотите оставить числовые ID (хотя вряд ли они являются хоть на каплю более производительными, чем небольшие текстовые), то придется мириться с этим и использовать их. В остальном ничего нового и более удобно изобрести все равно не получится.

Comment: Каюсь, я не знал, что varchar хранится как строка переменной длины (и название мне почему-то ни о чем не говорило). Но теперь я знаю, что в этом случае нужно использовать `CHAR(2)`.
Сильно сомневаюсь, что MySQL будет как-то оптимизировать работу с 2-байтной строкой, что это будет лучше 4-8 байтового INT-а. Но и хуже быть не должно. Думаю, стоит заморочиться с выбором кодировки — ASCII.